# Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Define $H^+=\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (\delta I+H^*H)^{-1}H^*$ as Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse of arbitrary matrix $H$. How can we show that $HH^+H=H$.i.e. it satisfies the first property of [Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Limit_relations).

I have tried the following:
$$
\begin{align}
HH^+H= & H (\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (\delta I+H^*H)^{-1}H^*)H\\ 
=& H (\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (\delta I+H^*H)^{-1}H^*H)\\
=& H (\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (\delta I+H^*H)^{-1})(\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (\delta I+H^*H)))\\ 
=& H \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \bigg[(\delta I+H^*H)^{-1} (\delta I+H^*H)\bigg]\\
=&H.
\end{align}$$

Is it alright? Anyone  hints or suggestions?

Comment: no, it isn't right. You can't separate the limits if it leads to indeterminate forms.

Comment: Your idea was great, but firstly it was needed to show that the limit $\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (\delta I+H^*H)^{-1}H^*$ exists, which seems not trivial, at least at first glance.